# How would I parse 'Front Matter' with Python

Tags: python, yaml

I can't seem any examples of how to parse 'Front Matter' with Python. I have the following:

```
---
name: David
password: dwewwsadas
email: david@domain.com
websiteName: Website Name
websitePrefix: websiteprefix
websiteDomain: domain.com
action: create
---
```

and I am using the following code:

```
listing = os.listdir(path)
for infile in listing:
    stream = open(os.path.join(path, infile), 'r')
    docs = yaml.load_all(stream)
    for doc in docs:
        for k,v in doc.items():
            print k, "->", v
    print "\n",
```

I keep getting errors because of the second set of `---`

Answer (score 6):

I know it is an old question, but I just faced the same problem  and used `python-frontmatter`. Here is an example to add a new variable to the **Front matter**:

```
import frontmatter
import io
from os.path import basename, splitext
import glob

# Where are the files to modify
path = "en/*.markdown"

# Loop through all files
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    with io.open(fname, 'r') as f:
        # Parse file's front matter
        post = frontmatter.load(f)
        if post.get('author') == None:
            post['author'] = "alex"
            # Save the modified file
            newfile = io.open(fname, 'w', encoding='utf8')
            frontmatter.dump(post, newfile)
            newfile.close()
```

**Source**: [How to parse frontmatter with python](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/en/how-to-parse-frontmatter-with-python/)

Answer (score 3):

The `---` starts new documents and that causes your second document to be empty, and `doc` to be `None` for the second part. You walk over the key, value pairs of the `doc` as if every `doc` is a Python `dict` or equivalent type, but `None` is not, so you should test for that inside your loop (there are of course multiple ways to do that, and on what to do if `doc` is not a `dict`):

```
....
for doc in yaml.load_all(stream):
    if hasattr(doc, 'items'):
        for k, v in doc.items():
            print k, "->", v
    else:
        print doc
```